# How to display tooltip for all thumbnails in a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, tooltip

I use a script to get **Bootstrap [tooltip](/questions/tagged/tooltip)** for some thumbnails in a part of my **[wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress)** site.

How can I display tooltips in all part of my site without having to copy/paste the code on each page ? Is there a plugin for this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. Please explain your problem better and show us your code.

Comment: i want only one thing, display tooltip for any thumbnail

Answer (score 1):

This plug-in is the best for your purpose

https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-tooltips/

or try this one

https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-tooltips/

If you have your own script, you can enqueue it with a function like this :

```
enqueue_script_function() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/yourscript.js', array(), '1.0.0', true ); /*see wp codex*/
};

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_script_function' );
```

you just have to write that in a php file in wp-content/mu-plugins/ (create it if not exists)